# How can I use regular expression to extract CSS rules from a string

Tags: javascript, css, regex

In Javascript, I have a CSS selectors and I would like to extract the rules:

```
var cssOriginalString = 'p:hover { color: red; font-weight: bold;}';
var cssFinalString = 'color: red; font-weight: bold;';
```

My goal is to group all the rules inside an array:

```
var rulesArray = ['color: red;', 'font-weight: bold;'];
```

Any idea?

-- [appcropolis](http://appcropolis.com)

Answer (score 2):

You could try using regex:

```
[a-z-]+ *:[^:;]+;
```

The `[a-z-]+` matches the css attribute names. I'm pretty sure they're lower case letters and hyphens, based on [W3schools CSS attributes reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp). However you could modify this if you feel differently (allow capital letters, etc). The loosest possible regex I'd recommend would be `[\w-]+`, which allows letters, numbers, underscore, and hyphen.

The `*:` is the separating colon, spaces allowed around it.

The `[^:;]+;` is the attribute value followed by a semi-colon. I've said that the attribute value can't contain a colon `:` or semi-colon `;` to prevent it from matching across multiple attributes. You could also try `.*?;` here (the `?` is important to make the match non-greedy, so it doesn't match over multiple attributes).

Comment: I was only linking to it as a list of CSS attributes, not as a learning resource.

Comment: It works... the only problem is that I only get the first rule.

Comment: You have to keep matching, not match just once. In python you'd use `findall` instead of `find`. I'm sure there's something similar in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to be asking for a regular expression, but it is very general.  I need to know a lot more about the input string (for example, can you have two rulesets on the same line?  Can you have one ruleset on multiple lines?  Is it possible or a concern for "}" to appear in a rule?  What about @ queries?).  A very simplistic expression for a single ruleset on a single line:

```
cssOriginalString.replace(/.*{([^}]+)}/, '$1');​​​
```

Comment: This is great! it does exactly what I need.